# FOSJsRoutingBundle does not see a route from FOSRESTBundle

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony, fosrestbundle

I want to access an API route to a FOSRESTBundle Controller from my JS. I'm using the FOSJSRoutingBundle, but the route is not visible (I'm getting the 'the route xxx does not exist' error.

This is an action from my controller:

```
namespace ApiBundle\Controller;


use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Get;

class AjaxController extends FOSRestController{

/**
 * @Get("/someaction", name="someaction")
 */
public function someAction()
{
    $response = 'some response';
    $view = $this->view($response,200);
    return $this->handleView($view);
}
}
```

This route is accessible via curl requests and by hardcoding it in the JS file, but I don't want to hardcode it. So i tried this in the JS file (after installing the JSRoutingBundle of course):

```
function prepareChart() {
$url = Routing.generate('someaction');
$.get( $url, function( data ) {
    <do something>
}, "json" );
}
```

Here is the routing.yml entry:

```
  ajax:
  resource: "@ApiBundle/Controller/AjaxController.php"
  prefix: /ajax/
  type: rest
  options:
    expose: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem - the FOSRestBundle does not support the 'name' attribute - the path to my controller was autogenerated and I had to retrieve its name from list of all routes by executing php app/console debug:router in the console.